# How to revoke the app access from Instagram using API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We can remove the app access from Instagram from here
https://www.instagram.com/accounts/manage_access/ in Instagram. How can we remove the access from API ?

While Inspecting the call when I hit the remove access button, I found that the Instagram app token is passed in POST method and getting *"status": "ok"* from this endpoint https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/web/oauth/revoke_access/
When I tried in Postman it's not working because I'm not logged in. I tried by passing the access token in payload its not working. I'm having the app token and access token. Expecting to get the *"status": "ok"* that mean access removed from Instagram.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking at the API call that is made from the browser - i.e. it has the context of a logged in user. It's not meant to be called from an external application.

I guess I am building something similar to you. There doesn't appear to be any revoke endpoint - this is where I have been looking https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api

My solution for now to remove access from our end is to simply delete the token. This still leaves the application in the https://www.instagram.com/accounts/manage_access/ page though, so it is not ideal. If we get a deauth request from Instagram in the future for a user we will simply ignore it as there would be nothing to do from our end.

Hopefully we will see a proper deauth method that we can call remotely in the future.